# How to do a search procedure by name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble creating my procedure.

I would like a procedure to search by name using like, but I cannot use it with my variable.

Script

```
alter Procedure [dbo].[spPesquisaTudo](
    @Nome varchar(150)
--, @CPF varchar(14)
)
  As Begin

Set NoCount on;

Select 

    clientes.ClienteId
,   clientes.Nome
,   clientes.CPF
,   clientes.Endereco
,   clientes.Whatsapp
,   clientes.Telefone
,   clientes.DataCriacao
,   clientes.DataModificacao

From dbo.Clientes clientes

Where clientes.Nome like '%Nome%'

End
```

[image]

Comment: try `clientes.Nome like '%' + @Nome + '%'`

Comment: Do not use `SP` prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of local variable if you would like to do wild card search based on the user input or user can give name like '%sth%' while running the procedure. But local variable will be good option I assume.

```
alter Procedure [dbo].[spPesquisaTudo](
    @Nome varchar(150)
--, @CPF varchar(14)
)
  As Begin

Set NoCount on;
DECLARE @NOME_N VARCHAR(150) = (SELECT CONCAT('%', @Nome, '%'))

Select 

    clientes.ClienteId
,   clientes.Nome
,   clientes.CPF
,   clientes.Endereco
,   clientes.Whatsapp
,   clientes.Telefone
,   clientes.DataCriacao
,   clientes.DataModificacao

From dbo.Clientes clientes

Where clientes.Nome like  @NOME_N 

End
```